# TestInstrumentation in Xamarin project - INSTRUMENT_RESULT is 0 for passes, failed and inclusive

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, adb, android-instrumentation

Has anyone done instrumentation tests with Xamarin.Android? What am I missing?

I have created my project as mentioned here:

https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1649768-how-do-i-automate-an-android-unit-test-project-

However, when I run test cases in emulator using:

> adb shell am instrument -w
> @PACKAGE_NAME@/app.tests.TestInstrumentation

It executes, but it shows below results.

> Instrument_Result: passed:0
>
> Instrument_Result: failed:0
>
> Instrument_Result: inclusive :0

Can anyone let me know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

When an Android Unit Test project is created, I just place the `TestSuiteInstrumentation` subclass in the `MainActivity.cs` along with the `TestSuiteActivity` subclass:

#### TestSuiteInstrumentation Example:

```
[Activity(Label = "SomeUnitTests", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : TestSuiteActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        // tests can be inside the main assembly
        AddTest(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        // or in any reference assemblies
        // AddTest (typeof (Your.Library.TestClass).Assembly);

        // Once you called base.OnCreate(), you cannot add more assemblies.
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
    }
}

[Instrumentation(Name = "app.tests.TestInstrumentation")]
public class TestInstrumentation : TestSuiteInstrumentation
{
    public TestInstrumentation(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(handle, transfer) { }

    protected override void AddTests()
    {
        AddTest(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

#### Unit Tests:

This example is using the tests that the auto-generated via the Android Unit Test project:

```
[Test]
public void Pass()
{
    Console.WriteLine("test1");
    Assert.True(true);
}

[Test]
public void Fail()
{
    Assert.False(true);
}

[Test]
[Ignore("another time")]
public void Ignore()
{
    Assert.True(false);
}

[Test]
public void Inconclusive()
{
    Assert.Inconclusive("Inconclusive");
}
```

#### Run tests

- Compile and Deploy the unit test apk to your device or emulator.
- Run the tests via `adb`

  - Note: My unit test project is named `SomeUnitTests` and has no predefined manifest so the generated package name for this "app" becomes: `com.sushihangover.someunittests`

#### ADB command:

> adb shell am instrument -w com.sushihangover.someunittests/app.tests.TestInstrumentation

#### Test output:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: failed=1
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: inconclusive=1
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: passed=1
~~~
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: skipped=1
INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I am following the same approach.  But when I run "adb shell am instrument -w ..." command  results ends with 

    Instrument_Result: passed:0

    Instrument_Result: failed:0

    Instrument_Result: inclusive :0       What could be the possibility for this.?

Comment: @VishwasRao If you run your unit tests via the user interface on the device does it report the same results?

Comment: No, User interface detects my test cases. It reports all test cases are passed (22 tests cases passed). I assume issue is with Test instrumentation. 
I am trying to find out why it is not reported when I run "adb shell am instrument -w ..." ..?

Comment: @VishwasRao is your `TestInstrumentation` class defined in the same file as your Unit Test's MainActivity.cs file and loading the same test assembly via `AddTest`? i.e. something like : `AddTest(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`

Comment: It is in different file. And I am including that file for compilation. Yes, I am overriding Addtest method to add test assembly.

Comment: @VishwasRao Is the `AddTest` in both the TestInstrumentation and MainActivity class the same?

Comment: Yes. In AddTest method I am loading executing assembly, AddTest(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()) in both MainActivity and TestInstrumentation class.

Comment: @VishwasRao If the `TestInstrumentation` class execution is not finding any tests to execute, it is not finding any tests in the same assembly that your UnitTest's MainActivity AddTest is using since that is finding your tests. As a test, place the `TestInstrumentation` class in the same file as the Unit Test's MainActivity like I did in my answer's example, compile, install and re-run the tests (visually on the device and via adb) and compare the two results.

Comment: @Sushil Tried putting TestInstrumentation class in main activity file. Still no luck.  Is there any change required in manifest.?

Comment: @VishwasRao There is no user-defined manifest in an Android Unit Test application. Are you putting the TestInstrumentation in the **unit test** project? I would create a new Android Unit Test project and do not change anything other than adding the TestInstrumentation class to it and compile/install it/and run it with the 4 template generated tests... what  happens?

Comment: Hi I tried above steps, still no luck . Is it because of any xamarin references missing..?

Answer (score 0):

After lot of debugging I found out the issue.

There was an exception occurring in TestFixtureSetup due to dependency services, because of this no other test were running. This exception will not log any  error message so I was not able to find out the root cause easily.